# Load Dataset from Postresql database with EARTH fields

Tags: c#, windows, npgsql

I am using C# and Npgsql to access a Postresql data base

```
 I can load tables into a dataset using

 Dataset loaded_data;
 loaded_data.Clear();
 string query = "SELECT * FROM postretable";
 NpgsqlDataAdapter data_adapt = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(query,connection);
 data_adapt.Fill(loaded_data);

 However I get an error 
 "42883: no binary output function available for type earth" 
 when there are columns of type EARTH in the table. 
 Is there a way to provide a binary output function for EARTH ?
```

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

The earth type, which seems to depend on the cube type, doesn't come with binary input/output functions and so cannot be supported at the moment by Npgsql. This is a PostgreSQL-side limitation in the extension, and unfortunately you can't really do much about it. See https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/698, which says the same thing about cube.

However, the Npgsql 4.0.0 release (currently in preview/rc) contains native support for PostGIS, the PostgreSQL spatial extension, via the NetTopologySuite .NET library - [see the docs](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/types/nts.html). This should provide a more complete and accurate of doing this kind of spatial calculation, and is fully supported.